# How to Install Canon LBP6000 Printer Driver on QEMU?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, driver, qemu

- [Canon Printers and CUPS: ARM drivers availabile?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1118309#p1118309)
- Platform: Raspbian Stretch

I tried the link above but couldn't get it to work.In the driver guide it says I need to install some packages.

```
# yum install libgcc.i686
# yum install libstdc++.i686
# yum install popt.i686
# yum install libxml2.i686
```

Can you explain me how to install the driver? I want to install the packages via apt-get if possible.

Comment: Are you using `apt-get` or `yum`?

Comment: I am using apt-get. but i don't have x86 repository.

Comment: Try `http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-i386/`